# When is it appropriate to adjust an independent variable by regression before including it in a regression on the dependent variable of interest?

Tags: mixed-model, multiple-regression, linear-model, biostatistics, adjustment

I want to run a linear mixed regression in which, basically, I see whether the expression of a particular gene is associated with a trait exhibited by the animal. I'll use growth rate as an example. However, I need to take into consideration confounding factors, including those which impact growth rate (e.g. pedigree, year of birth) and those which impact the gene expression measurement (e.g. age of animal when it was measured). My current approach was to include all of these in the regression model, as well as some I haven't mentioned but you can see the idea. An example could be:

- `growth rate = birth year + gene expression + age of gene measurement + pedigree (as random term)`

It was suggested that another approach would be to adjust the gene expression measurement first, to take into account the age of measurement, before including it in the model. Essentially I would do:

1. Linear regression where gene expression = age of gene measurement; then for each gene expression value, I would add its residual to the overall mean to get the adjusted value
2. growth rate = birth year + adjusted gene expression + pedigree (random)

**My question is whether anyone has an example for me of the latter approach and advice on which is better for a model explaining growth rate, in this case?**

Initially I can see that the second approach reduces the number of terms in the model, which is nice for my relatively small dataset, but may make interpretation more difficult since I have used an adjusted variable. In my case, the absolute value of expression is not important but only whether it is significantly associated and should be further investigated; however, the size of the effect of this variable in the model could be interesting, e.g. does a doubling of gene expression increase growth by 50% or only 1% - that would be interesting to find out.

My other concern is that if I run the adjustment in this way, do I have to adjust my p-values for multiple testing?